# How can I achieve this smooth normal map?

Tags: texture-baking

Title is abit misleading. Couldn't find a good title that describe what I wanted to ask. I recently bought substance indie pack and while watching painter tutorial, I noticed something that I don't know how to achieve in blender.

(Apperantly I can add one image because I'm a newby)
The first is this crate and as you can see polygon count doesn't look that high:
The second is how it looks in substance:
And the third is the model before the tutor added normal map for this object:
[image]

**My Question**
It looks really smooth. When I try to create a height map from high poly to low poly, it's never this smooth. And more over, as you can see the second image looks like height map but the tutor clearly indicated that was a normal map(also added AC as well). Well to simply put, how can I achieve this in blender?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/creating-game-models-for-android/2937#2937

Comment: Please show us your normal baking results. The "unsmooth" one and how it looks like. It's impossible to tell what you are doing wrong otherwise. The question is very broad.