# What are some good low-poly scene techniques?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, light, shaders

Recently I have noticed that [low-poly](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?388394-Orc-Village-(Low-Poly-Style)) art has really come into [vogue](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vogue), and I thought it would be helpful if we could collect some helpful concepts and techniques in how to replicate this style.

How can you create [pig-art](https://www.youtube.com/user/pigartt) styled [low-poly](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/10/28/tutorial-your-first-lowpoly-scene/) scenes in [Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/)?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41421/how-to-achieve-dramatic-composition-with-low-poly-models

Comment: Do we really need to link Blender?  I mean this *is* a Blender site.  And "vogue"?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can:

- Use Ambient Occlusion in BI
- Use rougher materials
- Set up the Depth of Field setting to get a tilt-shift effect
- Use the ortographic camera instead of the perspective